# I got right-to-left typing direction in the textbox by accident. How can I undo it?

Tags: support, information-display

I accidentally changed my answer to type right-to-left via some hotkey:

[image]

How can I undo it, without refreshing the page?

Comment: I don't think this is an SE thing, probably an OS thing. What is your OS?

Comment: @MarkKirby Windows 10 x64

Comment: Try to press ctrl + left arrow + shift to set it back to left to right text.

Comment: @MarkKirby If ctrl + right arrow + shift is to make it right-to-left, then it isn't working, and I already refreshed the page where it was right-to-left

Comment: OK then what browser do you have?

Comment: @MarkKirby That was the right question; `Ctrl + Shift + X` on Firefox, Windows 10. You can post it as answer I'll accept - thanks.

Comment: You're lucky. Try to fix whole screen being upside-down after mis-clicking a key. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a feature of Stack Exchange, but of your browser. Pressing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>X</kbd> will reverse text direction in Firefox.

<kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left Shift</kbd> or <kbd>right Shift</kbd> will reverse text direction in [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser))-based browsers.

Comment: Actually, any `Ctrl` key would work; not just the one at the right. The `Shift` key is what affects the direction. Moreover, the `Ctrl+Shift` combination works for me on Firefox too. AFAIK, this is the default on Windows. I never encountered a program that supports switching directions where this combination didn't work.